# OpenCV runs out of memory when reading video file

Tags: python, opencv, video

This example of reading video from file with `cv2.VideoCapture` in python OpenCV runs out of memory:

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('file.mp4')
while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
```

It takes ~300 frames at 1920x1080 before it runs out.  Tested in both OpenCV 3.0.0 beta and 2.4.8, running in latest Pythonxy on Windows 7 64-bit.

What needs to be added to this code to make it not run out of memory but rather free each frame before reading the next frame?

Comment: How many frames are there in total in the video file?

Comment: @herohuyongtao: About 20000 frames in the sample file.

Comment: openCV uses `reference counting` and releases unneeded Mat memory by itself. So if you don't link the data of frame somwhere else, freeing the memory should not be necessary. In c++ there is a .release method of cv::Mat, I guess there is an equivalent for python which you could try.

Comment: you probably want to append your story to this [bug report](http://code.opencv.org/issues/3470)

Comment: @berak: yep, that's it.  do you know, is there an older version which *doesn't* have this mem leak?

Comment: sorry, don't know about it (i'm on master version, too). but things won't get better, unless you put *some pressure* behind the issue

Answer (score 3):

You can use `scikit-image` which has a video loader and supports `Opencv` and `Gstreamer` backends as per documentation. I have never used `Gstreamer`.

```
import cv2
from skimage.io import Video

cap = Video(videofile)
fc = cap.frame_count()
for i in np.arange(fc):
   z = cap.get_index_frame(i)
```

Now use the frame `z` for whatever you want to do!

Comment: Interesting suggestion, unfortunately it doesn't work for me:  cap = Video('test.mp4', backend="opencv") => raise ImportError("Opencv 2.0+ required")  I have OpenCV 3.0 :)

Comment: @Alex OK. Incase you wish to downgrade, you can download 64-bit py 2.7 compatible opencv 2.4.6 package from [link](http://users.ugent.be/~ashishku/python/opencv-python-2.4.6.win-amd64-py2.7.exe)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if(!frame)
        break;
```

to make sure the `frame` is valid to avoid reading frames forever even not valid.

Comment: Yes, clearly checking the result is a good idea.  But when I run my example, the ret value is always True, and frame is a valid frame, it runs out of memory while always reading valid frames.

Comment: I see. It now seems probably a bug to me. As @berak commented, you can report this to [bug report](http://code.opencv.org/issues/3470).